# Are two triangles with equal corresponding medians, congruent?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, plane-geometry

Is  the  hyperbolic  or  spherical  analogy of  the  following Euclidean fact, true?

> Two triangles  with equal corresponding medians are congruent.

More  precisely: Assume that $\Delta ABC$ and $  \Delta A'B'C'$ are two   triangles in the  hyperbolic  space $\mathbb{H}^2$ or elliptic  space $\mathbb{S}^2$ such that  $$AM_1=A'M_1',\; BM_2=B'M_2',\;CM_3=C'M_3'$$  where $M_i (M_i')$ in $XM_i(X'M_i')$ is the mid point of the edge opposite  to the vertex $X(X')$, respectively.

Under this condition, is there an isometry of the  corresponding space carrying the  first triangle  to the  second  one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**This is not true for $S^2$.** Namely, one can construct two convex non-isometric spherical triangles such that all medians have length $\frac{3\pi}{4}-\varepsilon$.

1) The first triangle is the standard equilateral triangle. Clearly medians of such triangles all have the same length and their length vary from $0$ to $\pi$.

2) The second triangle will be a perturbation of the following one. Take on $S^2$ two opposite points $A$ and $B$ and join them by two geodesics (of length $\pi$) that bound a sector with angle $\frac{3\pi}{4}$. Call one of these geodesics $AB$. And choose $C$ as the mid point of the other geodesic. It is easy to see that for this degenerate triangle all medians have length $\frac{3\pi}{4}$. Now, by perturbing slightly $A$, $B$ and $C$ one can decrease the lengths of all medians by the same amount.

*Note.* It is important in the second construction that by varying $A$ and $B$ as little as we want, we can achieve that the median starting from $C$ takes any length in $(0,\pi)$. However the length of two other medians stay close to $\frac{3\pi}{4}$.

**PS, hyperbolic case**. Concerning the hyperbolic case, it looks like the answer is positive. 
If I would like to prove it, I would do as follows.

i) Consider the map from the convex cone in $\mathbb R_{\ge 0}^3$ consisting of triples $(a,b,c)$ satisfying the (non-strict) triangle inequality to itself: lengths of sides $\to$ lengths of medians.

ii) Realise that this map if proper (preimage of compact is compact). And it is an isomorphism on the boundary on the cone.

iii) The map is a "diffeo" close to the point $(0,0,0)$ - because it is so for Euclidean triangles.

**iv)** *This is the most complicated bit* -- show that the map has non-vanishing differential. This is where one needs to make a calculation. But it looks very plausible.

v) If all the above holds then the map is an isomorphism. QED